# Specify max page size of a RadGrid?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, telerik, radgrid

Is there a property that allows me to specify the max page size of a Rad Grid?

I have a radgrid and it defaults to 10 but the user can change this. If there is 1000s of records, the user can specify 1000 and it'll take ages to render. Would like to limit the page size to like 50 or something.

SOLUTION

Thanks to HalfTrackMindMan, I have posted the solution.

```
protected void rgSearchResults_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewPageSize > 50)
    {
        e.Canceled = true;
        rgSearchResults.PageSize = 50;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the PageSizeChanged event of the RadGrid and if NewPageSize is to much set Canceled property value of GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs to true.

Comment: mmm... that's good thanks. Although I notice that NewPAgeSize is a readonly property. Is there any way to specify it as 50 if they go over the 50?

Comment: actually i specified the radgrid to 50 actually IN the pagesizechange event and it worked. Beauty!